# crash when trying to delete a vault in swift firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering how do i remove a value in firebase. I know i need to reference the child but i do i remove it?

I have my code below

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child(currentEmail).child(firebaseKey)

         ref.didChangeValue(for: currentEmail): { (error, reference) in

            if error != nil {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                print("There has been an error:\(error!)")

            }

            if(self.data.count >= 0){

                self.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            } else{

                self.data.remove(at: index)
                self.listView.reloadData()
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                //self.listView.deleteRows(at: [index], with: .automatic)
            }


            if(self.data.isEmpty){

                self.listView.reloadData()

                 SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }

        }
        )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Stack!

So to be honest i have no idea how your code compiles. On top of that, i have no idea what some of those values are. But i can tell you this: the way you're deleting the data is completely wrong. should look something like:

```
     ref.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reference) in
```

not

```
ref.didChangeValue(for: currentEmail): { (error, reference) in
```